# How do you create a column that increments based on a subset of rows?

Tags: postgresql, count

I'd like a way to have `org_ticket_count` increment each time a support ticket is created for that org. It'll probably have to find the highest `org_ticket_count` for that org and increment before inserting. Also, when a `support_ticket` is deleted, I'd still like the org_ticket_count to stay the same.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orgs (
  primary key (org_id),
  org_id  bigint generated always as identity
);

CREATE TABLE support_tickets (
  primary key (support_ticket_id),
  support_ticket_id  bigint generated always as identity,
  org_id             bigint references orgs,
  org_ticket_count   bigint
);

------------------------

-- Get old ticket count
      SELECT org_ticket_count
        INTO v_old_org_ticket_count
        FROM support_tickets
       WHERE org_id = v_org_id
    ORDER BY support_ticket_id
        DESC
       LIMIT 1;

-- Create new ticket count
          IF v_old_org_ticket_count IS NULL THEN
             -- this is the first issue
             v_new_org_ticket_count := 1;
        ELSE
             v_new_org_ticket_count := v_old_org_ticket_count + 1;
     END IF;

-- Create support ticket
INSERT INTO support_tickets (org_id, org_ticket_count)
     VALUES (v_org_id, v_new_org_ticket_count);
```

One flaw I'm seeing is that if you delete the most recent `support_ticket` for an `org`, it'll repeat the `org_ticket_count` on the next `support_ticket` and your total count will be off by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Triggers`:

1. Add one more column `ticket_count` in your table `orgs`. So new definition will be:

```
    CREATE TABLE orgs (
      primary key (org_id),
      org_id  bigint generated always as identity,
      ticket_count bigint default 0
    );
```

2. Create a trigger on `after insert` event of table `support_tickets`

**Trigger Function**

```
create or replace function trig_fun() 
returns trigger AS
$$
declare
count_ bigint;
begin

select ticket_count into count_ from orgs where org_id=new.org_id;

update support_tickets set org_ticket_count= count_+1 where support_ticket_id=new.support_ticket_id;

update orgs set ticket_count=count_+1 where org_id=new.org_id;


return new;

end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

**Trigger**

```
create trigger trig_on_insert 
after insert on 
support_tickets
for each row
execute procedure trig_fun()
```

This will do exactly what you want.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fa31cb4433056c343958d7f7ce068359)

Answer (score 1):

Do not materialize that. Drop `support_tickets.org_ticket_count`. It's redundant and can lead to inconsistencies. For convenience you can create a view using the window version of `count(*)` instead.

```
CREATE VIEW support_tickets_with_org_ticket_count
AS
SELECT support_ticket_id,
       org_id,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY org_id
                      ORDER BY support_ticket_id) org_ticket_count
       FROM support_tickets;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1f6a397e1cd582776b09476b183422cc)